# Unable to install korn sh package

Tags: software-installation

I need to install ksh because we have many scripts /bin/ksh that must run on crontab.

There is no internet in the VM (runnnig Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS) so I uploaded this package and copied it into `/tmp`. I have this error when I try to install it:

```
# apt install ksh_2020.0.0-5_arm64.deb
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ksh_2020.0.0-5_arm64.deb
```

---

I tried the following command:

```
apt install ./ksh_2020.0.0-5_arm64.deb
```

But it's not working because there are some missing packages:

```
# apt install ./ksh_2020.0.0-5_arm64.deb
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 grafana : Depends: libfontconfig1 but it is not installed
 ksh : Depends: binfmt-support but it is not installable
 libfontconfig1-dev : Depends: libfontconfig-dev (= 2.13.1-4.2)
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

As the VM can't be connected to the internet, I can't add the missing package.

Is there another way to install ksh, or to execute a ksh script?

Comment: Your system is behind on upgraded packages (it should report as 20.04.3 if fully updated), but try providing a path (ie. `./ksh_...`  (it's the path that makes it be recognized as a local package; you've told it to download & install a package with the name you provided - where non of course exists)

Answer (score -1):

Your system is behind on upgraded packages (it should report as [20.04.3](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/08/27/ubuntu-20-04-3-lts-released/) if fully updated)

Try providing a path, ie.

`apt install ./ksh_2020.0.0-5_arm64.deb`

it's the path that makes it be recognized as a local package; you've told it to download & install a package with the name you provided (ie. download & install `ksh_2020.0.0-5_arm64.deb`) where none of course exists)

Comment: At one stage the local files are found; but sorry I forget what release that occurs with

Comment: i tried and here is the result:   # apt install ./ksh_2020.0.0-5_arm64.deb
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 grafana : Depends: libfontconfig1 but it is not installed
 ksh : Depends: binfmt-support but it is not installable
 libfontconfig1-dev : Depends: libfontconfig-dev (= 2.13.1-4.2)
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

Comment: those packages are for *hirsute* or *impish* meaning you've most likely mucked up your sources (added packages or details for a non-focal (non-20.04) system. Your package appears to be correct (`ksh | 2020.0.0-5                    | focal/universe          | source, amd64, arm64, armhf, ppc64el, riscv64, s390x`)   -- note `libfontconfig-dev | 2.13.1-4.2ubuntu3 | hirsute | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, riscv64, s390x` which isn't a 20.04 package

Comment: The normal fix is to `sudo apt update` to check your sources for anything that doesn't belong there, plus any missing lines (but in your case it's something that doesn't belong that has been installed), then you do as it says, ie. `sudo apt -f install` after package source issues are fixed.

Comment: here is the result: apt -f install ksh_2020.0.0-5_arm64.deb
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ksh_2020.0.0-5_arm64.deb